# Copy contact list in app inventor

Tags: android, app-inventor

I am new to App Inventor. I am building an app for Blind people, so they could call easily. for that I want to access contact list. Its easy with phone number picker and contact picker as they gives list. But I am not able to read it line wise.Is there any way that I could copy all contacts to a database or a list and then easily read them line wise.

Thanks

Comment: unfortunately you can't read **all** contacts from the contact list with App Inventor. There only is the [contact picker](http://appinventor.mit.edu/explore/content/social.html#ContactPicker) you can pick one contact only.

Comment: It means I have to code that in eclipse. Thanks for support